# JavaScript Event (click), on each click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the background color on each click.

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var color = true;

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(color){
        body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
        color != color;
    }
    else if (!color){
        body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: correct `color != color;`  to `color = false` and \ or, simplify your function to `function(){ color ? body.style.backgroundColor = "purple" : body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; };`  altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small modification. You need to toggle the variable on every click.
You could simplify your code further by getting rid of the `if else` and replace it with `else`

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var color = true;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (color) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  // or equivalent with a ternary operator:
  body.style.backgroundColor = color ? "purple" : "green";

  // color != color is a comparison, but you want an assignment:
  color = !color;
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cacd73Le/1/)**

Comment: I see, i knew i was using the comparison wrong, i just couldn't put my finger on it :D